# How to read out error message detail in javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have a try/catch block and i am trying to print out the error message detail, which i get from backend

So, I get the response like this:

**Response payload**

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "id": "b01cf93d-8f62-4fc9-b7e7-1d912d5aa657",
      "title": "Runtime Error",
      "detail": "Name already exists",
      "status": "500"
    }
  ]
}
```

Bit if I am trying something like this:

```
   myMethod().then((res) => {
     ...   
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log("here is error", e)
    });
```

it gives me invalid object error and doesn't show the message. I also tried `JSON.stringify()` and access it like `e.errors[0].detail` but it didn't help.

How could I print the **detail** out?

Comment: If you get a valid  object from your backend, you won't handle any error.
You can throw error by hand when there is error message from your backend with managing it in .then(...)

Comment: @FrV so, the problem is on the backend side? But the thing is that in browser's debugging console in Response part I can see the details, but i can't print it out and it is a bit weird...

Comment: put the response you receive in .then from your backend. An exception can be handle only if there is a throw statement or a standart javascript Exception (like nullpointer)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
   myMethod().then((res) => {
     if (res.errors)
         throw res.errors
     ...
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log("here is error", e)
    });
```

Comment: it doesn't work - by the error it jumps not in then, but directly in catch